# How to display List View Items by column, from Json

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I am currently retrieving data from an online MySQL database and displaying it with in the application, but i have been having trouble formatting it to even a basic standard.

Code Snippet below showing the JSON Objects being retrieved and cycled through, then applied to a list view adapter.

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String CurrentUser="";
    String Benchpress="";
    String Squat="";
    String Deadlift="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfigLeaderboard.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject leaderboards;

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++) {
            leaderboards = result.getJSONObject(i);
            CurrentUser = leaderboards.getString(ConfigLeaderboard.KEY_CURRENTUSER);
            Benchpress = leaderboards.getString(ConfigLeaderboard.KEY_BENCHPRESS);
            Squat = leaderboards.getString(ConfigLeaderboard.KEY_SQUAT);
            Deadlift = leaderboards.getString(ConfigLeaderboard.KEY_DEADLIFT);
            dataList.add(CurrentUser + "                             " + Benchpress );
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("JSONArray length ",result.length() + "");
        }

    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    getLeaderboardData();
```

The main thing im really stuck on is actually just obtaining a basic layout where the retrieved data is separated neatly almost like columns. Now for this i understand a custom listview adapter would be required, but would a data model also be required? Given that im retreiving data from Json would this still apply. I just feel so fustrated and stuck

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution is a combination of the following

1. A custom "row" layout to replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` because that will only get you a single String item, not aligned columns
2. A simple Java class (commonly known as a POJO), to "bind" this JSON data to that view
3. An Adapter that `extends ArrayAdapter<Foobar>` where `Foobar` is the name of the class from step 2

Now, you *could* just add tabs to your string data to simulate columns, however you can't guarantee the data will align vertically.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As you highlighted adding tabs does not align the data vertically so unfortunately that is not an option in this instance. Could you walk me though the set up of this if you have the time of course. It would be very much appreciated and aid my understanding. Thank you

Comment: Sure, read over [this guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView), then drop down to "Using a Custom ArrayAdapter", and then optionally "Constructing Models from External Source"